# Review Audit Honeypot - Seems like a resource request

Tags: discussion, review-audits

I just failed on a review audit honeypot.

Can someone tell me why this isn't a resource request and why it shouldn't be closed (until it's revised)?

[What is an example of a continuation not implemented as a procedure?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/212057/what-is-an-example-of-a-continuation-not-implemented-as-a-procedure)

Comment: I am out of down and close votes today; plan to [fix this erroneously picked audit item tomorrow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/165773 "as described here")

Comment: @gnat: Thanks for looking into this!

Answer (score 1):

The title is what saves the question, IMO.

> What is an example of a continuation not implemented as a procedure?

The title steers the question towards "hey, I don't get this thing. Can someone explain it better?"

But I see and agree with your confusion.  This is the current last paragraph:

> Are there any examples of languages where a continuation is expressed in a more abstract way than a function? I know Scheme allows you to grab the current continuation in a first-class manner (call/cc), but even so, it seems that the one argument procedure passed to call/cc is simply given the current continuation in the form of another one argument procedure to which the call/cc'd function can apply its result.

The first sentence there is a polling based question, which would be grounds for closing the question.

So I changed it to this:

> To help my understanding, can an example be provided in a functional language where the continuation is expressed in a more abstract way than a function?

This avoids the poll, but still maintains the OPs request for a "real" example to explain the question.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the effort. Although I don't want to be confused with a bot. I wish someone could reverse my failed audit.

Comment: That's only possible for people with direct access to the database @JimG. If you _really_ want the audit to be cleared from your reviewing history, your only option is to contact SE directly. That said, in the extremely unlikely chance you find yourself edit-banned (which would be partially because of this failed audit), feel free to ping me in chat to clear the ban (that, I can do).

Comment: @JimG. I have failed a few audits, and there are several of those that I have gone back into the question and kicked it into the close review queue.  The review bans are flexible enough to allow for some mistakes without any / many issues for the occasional miss.  Worst case means that you'll see audit questions pop up more frequently.

Comment: @YannisRizos: Many thanks.